# Using Twain in Electron desktop application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, twain

I am developing a desktop application using React + Electron. My client is asking to use a scanner to scan his document, and then upload them to the server through the application.

Is there any successful way of implementing Twain in React?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may follow this https://www.dynamsoft.com/web-twain/docs/indepth/development/react.html

Comment: this solution is very costly, any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any successful way of implementing Twain in React?

Yes. There are a few commercial JavaScript libraries that allow you access scanners from a web page. For example, we offer one named [Scanner.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=scannerjs)